# How to create a common event for Multiple Controls

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

In My application i need to create a table with dynamically creating Rows based on the Content of the row,
For Ex:

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
                    <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                        <asp:TableHeaderCell>Is Max</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                        <asp:TableHeaderCell>Units</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                        <asp:TableHeaderCell>Cost</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" /></asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell><input type="text" name="sds" /></asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
```

I am Placing these table control in UpdatePanel.
Here i have written a CheckedChanged Event upon which i il create a new row from the codebehind. So the problem is to create a common event which needs to be used by all checkboxes in all rows which are even created dynamically.

Please Suggest if u know any solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the OnCheckedChanged event in code behind when creating the dynamic controls.

A short sample code, missing everything specific, showing the event subscription:

```
private void createControl () {
  CheckBox dynamicCheckbox = new CheckBox();
  /* properties */
  dynamicCheckbox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler( Common_CheckedChanged );
  /* add to control tree, etc. */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay. It will be very helpful if you provide a line of code, how to do this exactly?